# PhpStorm does not recognize Livewire Custom Component

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, laravel-livewire

All my custom components are working properly. But PhpStorm cannot <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> to the file.

`Provider.php`

```php
Livewire::component($alias, $class);
```

`Blade.php`

```html
<livewire:blog::share.side-menu />
```

For now PhpStorm can <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> to the file on Livewire component on `app/Http/Livewire`, but not on `modules/Blog/Livewire`.

Please help me to <kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> every Livewire component.

Comment: Such Laravel-specific navigation support is provided by the custom plugin, should be **Laravel Idea**. Please check [their help](https://laravel-idea.com/docs/overview) and [contact the author](https://github.com/laravel-idea/plugin/issues) if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to install Laravel plugin to index component files.

[image]

Comment: AFAIK 2) this plugin is not compatible with the latest stable 2022.2 version (2022.1 max) 2) does not actually support Livewire...

Comment: I already paid for `Laravel Idea`, it works perfectly with the normal Livewire component (component in `\app\Http\Livewire`) but not work on custom Livewire component (component in `modules\Blog\Livewire`).
All the custom components are working normally, but cannot  `Ctrl + Click` to open the file.